# How to compare 2 passwords in the registration form and give an error if incorrect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a registration form with email, password and password confirmation. How can I compare passwords and throw an error if the passwords don't match and validate if everything is correct?

```
<form id="registerForm" method="POST" action="/register" class="form2">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input placeholder=" Email" type="text" name="email">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input placeholder="Напишите пароль" type="password" id="password" name="password">
                <label>Повторите пароль</label>
                <input placeholder="Repeat password" id="password-confirm" name="password-confirm" type="password">
                <input type="hidden" name="regcapch" id="capchField" />
                
                <input id="registerSubmit" style="background: #008DCC; color: white;" value="Зарегистрироваться" type="submit" name=""/>
            </form>
```

Tell me how to write a code that compares the Password field and the Repeat password field.

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: You can find solution here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648374/check-if-two-fields-has-the-same-value-with-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if two fields has the same value with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648374/check-if-two-fields-has-the-same-value-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick tutorial you can do:

1. Use JavaScript and the onchange event on the input fields.
2. When the onchange is triggered, compare the values of the fields, if they're the same. You can get the input field element with document.getElementById.
3. Disable the submit button if they're not the same.
4. You can also validate the length and characters in the onchange event.

Please try this on your own and post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if needed as @Andy stated.